# Find the maximum score in a given array which can be found by either multiplying or adding

Tags: c++, math, modulo

```
You are given an array A of K integers where Ai denotes page number of a book. To compute the score, you can either add or multiply the last digit of the page numbers.
You have to find the maximum score you can get. Since the score can be quite large, output the score modulo 1000000007

Note: The book contains N pages. Also, you need to follow the order in which the page numbers are given in the array. Initially, your score is 0.

Input format :

First line: Two space seperated integers N and K.
Next line: K space seperated integers denoting the page numbers.
Output format :

Output the maximum score you can get. Print it modulo 1000000007
Input Constraints:

1<=N<=10^9
1<=k<=10^9

SAMPLE INPUT:
50 3
2 35 23

SAMPLE OUTPUT:
30

Explanation
Last digit of all page numbers are: 2, 5, and 3.
Initial score = 0
We add 2 to the score which now becomes 2, multiply with 5 making the score 10, finally we multiply with 3 making the score 30 which is the maximum score.

Output 30 % (10^9+7) = 30.
```

I encountered the same question in an online test I gave recently.
Instead N was the no of books and K is the size of the array.Both were given as inputs.
Here is what I did:

```
int main() {
 long long n, k;
 long long m = 1000000007;
 cin >> n >> k;
 vector<int> arr(k, 0);
 for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
  cin >> arr[i];
 }
 long long prod = 1;
 long long sum = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
  if(arr[k] < n){
     prod = ((prod % m) * (arr[k] % 10)) % m;
     sum = ((sum% m) + (arr[k] % 10)) % m;
     prod = max(prod, sum);
     sum = max(prod, sum);
  }
 }
 cout << prod % m << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

As you can see instead of handling for 1 and 2, I am checking for max value of the product and sum at every iteration and updating both the product and sum with it.
I got two test cases passed and rest gave wrong answer.Why is it so?

Here is the question link, if anyone needs to give it a try.

[The Book Game Problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/book-cricket-8cb02499/)

Comment: Run the program in the debugger that came with your development environment (and get better tools if you don't have a debugger). Feed in one of the test cases that fails and step through the program paying careful attention to see where the program does something you don't expect like store the wrong value or take the wrong path. The unexpected is a almost always a bug and when it isn't it means your expectations are wrong. Either case needs fixing.

Comment: @john I think I have done the greedy approach here and it works.At each step I am updating the max possible value, this ensures that my final ans will be maximum

Comment: @Xtense Yes, ignore what I said, I wasn't thinking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem asks you to add OR multiply the last digit of the page numbers to make the resultant score as large as possible.

In this case, you should add when the digit is 0 or 1, and multiply otherwise.

For example,
Let the last digit sequence be

[1 0 2 5 8 1]

0. 'score' is initialized to be 0.
1. add 1 (score: 1)
2. add 0 (score: 1)
3. multiply by 2 (score: 2)
4. multiply by 5 (score: 10)
5. multiply by 8 (score: 80)
6. add 1 (score: 81)

and before submitting the answer, you need to modulo it by 1000000007.
so,

```
score %= 1000000007
```

in your code, you are calculating the prod and the sum separately, which is not what you are asked to do. Also, you are sumbitting only the 'prod' value, while it is not always the maximum value (consider multiplying some number by 0)

And additionally, you are modulo-ing the intermediate values (prod and sum) which can lead to wrong answer. The modulo should not be used to calculate the score, but to truncate the result of the score digits.

So, my answer is,

Calculate the intermediate values and assign it to one variable named 'score' (don't separate the product and the sum), and modulo the value just before printing the output (don't modulo it every time you add or multiply)

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is suppose you take ```[1,2,3]```. Here as per your logic we will add 1 to score which become 1.Then in next iteration,since the digit is 2,we will multiply.But that wrong since it should be ```1+2=3``` instead of ```1 * 2 = 2```.Here 3 is the larger value and hence that case need to handled separately.What I have done is I covered all the cases with my logic.I have understood the modulo thing and I have tried removing them as well.I have updated the question with its link, if you want to try

Comment: In the question I have linked, when you give the custom test case as ```[1, 2, 3```, it returns 6 instead of 9 and hence I think there is some fault in the question

Comment: Oh, you're right. I missed that case! Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: About the score resulting 6 instead of 9, maybe the person who wrote the question missed what you pointed out as well??